# make pop up view disappear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have button, when I click that button, a view pops up.

```
testingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popupTable), for: .touchUpInside)

 @objc func popupTable(){

        self.opaqueView = self.setUpPopView()
        mainView.addSubview(opaqueView)

        print("button clicked")
    }
```

if the view is present, I want to click on the button again and make the view disappear.

```
if tinyView.isHidden == false {
             tinyView.isHidden = false
            self.testingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePopUp), for: .touchUpInside)
 }else{
             tinyView.isHidden = true
            mainView.addSubview(tinyView)
        }
```

Which it does but when I click on the button a third time (pop up view is not present) i want the pop up view to appear again but it doesn't.

show pop up

```
func setUpPopView () -> UIView {

        tinyView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.99, blue:0.99, alpha:1.0)
        tinyView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        tinyView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        tinyView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
        tinyView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        tinyView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9

        let post: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 10, width: 150, height: 50))
        post.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        post.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for:UIControlState.normal)
        post.setTitle("All Post", for: .normal)
        post.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        post.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePopUp), for: .touchUpInside)
        tinyView.addSubview(post)

    }
```

remove pop up

```
@objc func removePopUp(_ sender: AnyObject){
        self.tinyView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use one action only and check the visibility of the pop up view in the action. According to the visibility of the view you can then show or hide the pop up. 
Like this:

```
@objc func popupAction() {
    If self.popUpView.isHidden {
        // Pop up view is hidden, so show the pop up view again
    } else {
        // Pop up view is visible, so hide the pop up view
    }
}
```

Also change this:

```
if tinyView.isHidden == false
{ 
    tinyView.isHidden = false
    self.testingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePopUp), for: .touchUpInside) 
}else{ 
    tinyView.isHidden = true
    mainView.addSubview(tinyView)
}
```

With this:

```
if tinyView.isHidden == false
{ 
    tinyView.isHidden = true
    tinyView.removeFromSuperview()
}else{ 
    tinyView.isHidden = false
    mainView.addSubview(tinyView)
}
```

Comment: the button still does not work on the third click. It works for the first click, the pop up shows, the second click, the button disappears but the third click the button doesn't work to show the pop us view. I added a print statment to see if the button is being clicked and it is.

Comment: What did you use to show and hide the popup? Can you show me the code?

Comment: Well if you look at your code then you'll see that you're setting self.tinyView.isHidden = false when it is already false. So that's the issue, i guess.

Comment: with or without that statement gives the same result

Comment: i added a print statement to determine if the view is present or not. Every click prints out view is not present. Is there another way to check if the view is present other than popview.ishidden?

Comment: its not working. is there a way I can make an action for a second click of a button/

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `removeFromSuperview`. You should not be saying `if`. It all just adds unnecessary complications.

If your goal is to show and hide a view, just show it and hide it: toggle its hiddenness, which is a one-liner:

```
tinyView.isHidden = !tinyView.isHidden
```

That way, if it is invisible, it becomes visible, and if it is visible, it becomes invisible. In Swift 4.2, it's even simpler:

```
tinyView.isHidden.toggle()
```

That's all! You don't need know whether it's already hidden, you don't need to remove it from the superview. No `if`, no nothing. You just invert its hiddenness each time you want to hide or show it.